# Cant update form data laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I’m  trying to update a modal form but for some reason nothing changed after I click the update button. I have tried to dd `request->role_name`, but it looks like it didn’t catch the value that I input with select form. The delete and create works perfectly fine. I will provide the create and delete controller if you all want to know.

The table that I used:

```
bas_role
id
name
bas__app
id
app_name
bas_role_app
id
role_id(f_key)
app_name(f_key)
```

Route:

```
Route::get('/roleapp', 'RoleAppController@display');
Route::post('/roleapp/update/{roleapp}', 'RoleAppController@update');
Route::get('ajaxdata/getapp','RoleAppController@getroleapp')->name('ajaxdata.getroleapp');
```

Controller:

```
    public function display(Request $request)
        {
    
    
    
    
    
            $routes =  preg_match('/([a-z]*)@([a-z]*)/i', Route::currentRouteAction(), $matches);
            $routes = $matches[0];
            $action = $matches[2];
            if (Auth::check()) {
    
                $id = Auth::id();
               DB::beginTransaction();
    
            try {
               $profile_data = User::find($id);
                 ActivityLog::create([
    
                    'inserted_date' => Carbon::now()->TimeZone('asia/jakarta'),
                    'username' => $profile_data->username,
                    'application' =>$routes,
                    'creator' => "System",
                    'ip_user' => $request->ip(),
                    'action' => $action,
                    'description' => $profile_data->username. " is looking at roleApp",
                    'user_agent' => $request->server('HTTP_USER_AGENT')
                 ]);
    
    
    
            // $pagination = TRUE;
            $app =DB::table('bas_role_app')
            ->join('bas_role_app','bas_app.app_name','=','bas_role_app.app_name')
            ->join('bas_role','bas_role_app.role_id','=','bas_role.id')
            ->from('bas_app')
            ->distinct()
            // ->where('role_user.role_id', 4)
            ->select('bas_role_app.app_name','bas_role.name','bas_role_app.id','bas_role_app.role_id')
    
            //        ->from('bas_app')
            //        // ->where('role_user.role_id', 4)
            ->groupBy('bas_app.app_name','bas_role.name','bas_role_app.id')
            ->Orderby('bas_role_app.id')
            ->get();
                  //   dd($app);
             $bas_role = Role::distinct()->select('id','name')->get();
           $bas_app =App::distinct()->select('id','app_name')->get();
                    DB::commit();
                } catch (\Exception $ex) {
                    DB::rollback();
                return response()->json(['error' => $ex->getMessage()], 500);
                }
    
             return view('/roleapp', ['app' => $app, 'bas_app'=> $bas_app, 'bas_role' => $bas_role]);
         //   return view('/roleapp', ['app' => $app, 'bas_app' => $bas_app]);
        }else {
    
            return view("login");
        }
    }
    
    
    
    public function getroleapp(){
    
        $app = DB::table('bas_role_app')
        ->join('bas_role_app','bas_app.app_name','=','bas_role_app.app_name')
        ->join('bas_role','bas_role_app.role_id','=','bas_role.id')
        ->from('bas_app')
        ->select('bas_role_app.app_name','bas_role.name','bas_role_app.id')
        ->get();
        return Datatables::of($app)->make(true);
    }

   public function update(Request $request, $id)
     {
        $routes =  preg_match('/([a-z]*)@([a-z]*)/i', Route::currentRouteAction(), $matches);
        $routes = $matches[0];
        $action = $matches[2];
        if (Auth::check()) {

            $idUser = Auth::id();
           DB::beginTransaction();
    
        DB::table('bas_role_app')
        ->where('id', $id)
        ->update([
            'role_id' => $request->role_name ,
            'app_name' => $request->app_name,
        ]);
     //   dd($request->role_name);



        return redirect('/roleapp')->with('message', 'Role App data update success!');
    } else {

        return view("login");
    }
```

RoleApp.blade.php

```
     @extends('layouts.master')
        @section('title','Role App')
        @section('content')
        
        @if($errors->any())
        <div class="alert alert-danger alert-dismissible fade show" role="alert">
            {{ implode(', ', $errors->all(':message')) }}
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close">
                <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
            </button>
        </div>
        @endif
        
        @if(session()->has('message'))
        <div class="alert alert-success">
            {{ session()->get('message') }}
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close">
                <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
            </button>
        </div>
        @endif
        
        
        <div class="container mt-5">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-12">
                    <!-- Modal -->
                    <div class="float-left">
                            <div class="form-group mx-sm-3 mb-2">
                            <form class="form-inline">
        
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModalCenter">
                                <i class="ni ni-fat-add"></i>
                                </button>
                            </div>
                            </form>
                    </div>
        
        
                    <div class="modal fade" id="exampleModalCenter" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalCenterTitle" aria-hidden="true">
                        <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
                            <div class="modal-content">
                                <div class="modal-header">
                                    <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLongTitle">Add New Role</h5>
                                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                                        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                                    </button>
                                </div>
        
    //Create new role app
                                <div class="modal-body">
                                    <form action="roleapp/create" method="POST">
                                        {{ csrf_field() }}
        
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <label class="control-label">Role Name:</label>
                                             <select class="form-control select2bs4" data-live-search="true" data-placeholder="Choose Role Name" tabindex="1" name="role_name" style="width: 100%;" required>
                                                <option value="">Choose Role Name.......</option>
                                                     @foreach ($bas_role as $category)
                                                        <option value="{{ $category->id }}">{{ $category->name }}</option>
                                                     @endforeach
                                            </select>
                                        </div>
        
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <label class="control-label">App Name:</label>
                                             <select class="form-control select2bs4" data-placeholder="Choose App Name" tabindex="1" name="app_name" style="width: 100%;" required>
                                                <option value="">Choose App Name.......</option>
                                                     @foreach ($bas_app as $category)
                                                        <option value="{{ $category->app_name }}">{{ $category->app_name }}</option>
                                                     @endforeach
                                            </select>
                                        </div>
        
                                </div>
                                <div class="modal-footer">
                                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal"><i class="ni ni-fat-remove"></i></button>
                                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary"><i class="ni ni-check-bold"></i></button>
                                </div>
                                </form>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
        
        
        //show role app table
                    <table class="table table-striped" id="app">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th scope="col">id</th>
                                <th scope="col">Role Name</th>
                                <th scope="col">App Name</th>
                                <th scope="col">Action</th>
                                <th scope="col">Action</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody id="dynamic-row">
        
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                    @foreach ($app as $p)
                    <div class="modal fade" id="modal_edit_{{$p->id}}" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true">
                        <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
                            <div class="modal-content">
                                <div class="modal-header">
                                    <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLongTitle">Edit RoleApp</h5>
                                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                                        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                                    </button>
                                </div>
    
    
    //Update a role app
                                <div class="modal-body">
                                <form id="app_form_{{$p->id}}" action="{{ url('roleapp/update', [$p->id]) }}" method="POST">
                                <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}" form="app_form_{{$p->id}}" />
        
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label class="control-label">Role Name:</label>
                                     <select class="form-control select2bs4" data-placeholder="Choose Role Name" tabindex="1" name="role_name" style="width: 100%;" required>
                                      <option value="{{$p->id}}">{{$p->name}}</option>
                                             @foreach ($bas_role as $category)
                                                <option value="{{ $p->role_id }}">{{ $category->name }}</option>
                                             @endforeach
                                    </select>
                                </div>
        
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label class="control-label">App Name:</label>
                                     <select class="form-control select2bs4" data-placeholder="Choose App Name" tabindex="1" name="app_name" style="width: 100%;" required>
                                         <option value="{{$p->app_name}}">{{$p->app_name}}</option>
                                             @foreach ($bas_app as $category)
                                                <option value="{{ $p->app_name }}">{{ $category->app_name }}</option>
                                             @endforeach
                                    </select>
                                </div>
        
                                </div>
                                <div class="modal-footer">
                                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal"><i class="ni ni-fat-remove"></i></button>
                                    <button type="submit" form="app_form_{{$p->id}}" class="btn btn-primary"><i class="ni ni-check-bold"></i></button>
                                </div>
                                </form>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    @endforeach
//delete a roleapp
        
                    @foreach ($app as $p)
                    <div class="modal fade" id="modal_hapus_{{$p->id}}" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true">
                        <div class="modal-dialog">
                            <div class="modal-content">
                                <div class="modal-header">
                                    <h5 class="modal-title">Data akan dihapus</h5>
                                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                                        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                                    </button>
                                </div>
                                <div class="modal-body">
                                    Data yang dihapus tidak dapat dikembalikan!
                                </div>
                                <div class="modal-footer">
                                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" data-dismiss="modal"><i class="ni ni-fat-remove"></i></button>
                                    <a href="{{ url('roleapp/delete', [$p->id]) }}" class="btn btn-danger"><i class="ni ni-check-bold"></i></a>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    @endforeach
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        
        <link  rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('css/breadcrumb.css') }}">
        
        <script>
        
            //load search, individual or not
            var row = 0;
        
                $(document).ready(function() {
        
        
                    $('#app thead tr').clone(true).appendTo( '#app thead' );
            $('#app thead tr:eq(1) th').each( function (i) {
                if (row < 3) {
                    var title = $(this).text();
                    $(this).html('<input type="text" placeholder="Search ' + title + '" />');
                } else {
                    $(this).html('');
                }
                row++;
                $( 'input', this ).on( 'keyup change', function () {
                    if ( table.column(i).search() !== this.value ) {
                        table
                            .column(i)
                            .search( this.value )
                            .draw();
                    }
                } );
            } );
        
            //load datatable processing, using serverside yajra, with pagination option, also action button as well
        
            var table =   $('#app').DataTable({
        
                    "processing": true,
                    "serverSide": true,
                    "ajax": "{{ route('ajaxdata.getroleapp') }}",
                    "lengthMenu" : [[20, 50, 100, 500, 1000, -1],[20, 50, 100, 500, 1000, "All"]],
                    "columns":[
                        { "data": "id" },
                        { "data": "name" },
                        { "data": "app_name" },
                        {
                            sortable: false,
                            "render": function ( data, type, full, meta ) {
                                return '<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal_edit_'+full.id+'"><i class="ni ni-single-02"></i></button>';
                            }
                        },
        
                        {
                            sortable: false,
                            "render": function ( data, type, full, meta ) {
                                return '<button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal_hapus_'+full.id+'"><i class="ni ni-fat-delete"></i></button>';
                            }
                        },
        
                ],
             });
        
        
             $('.selectpicker').selectpicker({
                style: 'btn-default',
              //  size: false
            });
        
        } );
            </script>
        
        
        
        
        {{--
        
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.13.1/js/bootstrap-select.min.js"></script> --}}
        
            @endsection
```

Answer (score 0):

please change the route `HTTP` verb for update -

> Like Below

```
Route::put('/roleapp/update/{roleapp}', 'RoleAppController@update');

or
Route::match(['PUT','PATCH'],'/roleapp/update/{roleapp}', 'RoleAppController@update')
```

and update your blade view -

```
//Update a role app
 <div class="modal-body">
 <form id="app_form_{{$p->id}}" action="{{ url('roleapp/update', [$p->id]) }}" method="POST">
  @method('PUT')
  @csrf
```

Comment: sorry it still doesnt work, the data didnt change at all, it tried to comment di input type section and uncomment it, still doesnt work